# Integrating the Navmii SDK for android

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm getting error while trying to Add the dependencies of the navmii sdk

I'm following the documentation to add the dependencies:
http://navmii.com/android-sdk-documentation/

In order to add the SDK library to your application insert the following code into your app’s build.gradle:

```
repositories {
maven {
    url 'TODO'
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.navmii.android:navmiisdk:1.0.0.36167@aar') // TODO update the version
}

i got error massage says : Error:(18, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.navmii.android:navmiisdk:1.0.0.36167@aar] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Open File

My gradle.build file :

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'TODO'
        }
    }}


dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    compile ('com.navmii.android:navmiisdk:1.0.0.36167@aar')

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
 allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

     }
   }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: What is `url 'TODO'` ?

Comment: @ADM I don't know i'm following the documentation.

Comment: http://navmii.com/android-sdk-documentation/ @ADM